# "Query is not supported" for Video dimension

Tags: youtube-api, user-activity, youtube-analytics

I have a problem with Youtube Analytics API documented here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/content_owner_reports#Activity_Reports

I retrieve a "400 Bad request" when I try to perform this request via APIs explorer:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DUC-7h5ZrKE-igqZy31ZvFWGg&start-date=2012-01-31&end-date=2012-04-30&metrics=views&dimensions=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

The error is:
"The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports for a list of supported queries."

The error occours only when I use "video" as dimension (the documentation says "video" is a supported dimension).
All other requests work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Such a brilliant error message isn't it? "Bluh! It don't work". Nice one Google

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is for the same problem:

[Unable to retrieve video metrics using Youtube Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982845/unable-to-retrieve-video-metrics-using-youtube-analytics-api)

you need to sort by descending views if you want to run a dimensions=video report, and you can only retrieve at most 10 results