# YouTube API - Video as a Dimension is not working, because maxResults does not work

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, google-apps, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I am trying to use Google AppsScript to sort all my YouTube videos in a sheet by the amount of revenue they earned in the last month.  However I keep getting an error when I set the 'dimensions' to video:

```
Error:{  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"badRequest",
            "message":"The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports for a list of supported queries."
         }
      ],
      "code":400,
      "message":"The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports for a list of supported queries."
   }
}(line 53,
file "Code",
project "YoutubeAnalytics")
```

Here is my code:

```
var analyticsResponse = YouTubeAnalytics.reportsQuery('channel==' + channelId,
    oneMonthAgoFormatted,
    todayFormatted,
    'views', 

{
    dimensions:
    'video',
    maxResults:
    5,
    sort:
    '-views'
});
```

If I simply change 'video' to 'day' or '7DayTotals' it works as expected, as these are also example dimensions listed here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims

(Interestingly, and a possible hint, the 'gender' dimension does not work either and throws the same error as above')

I suspect, from looking at similar questions on StackOverflow, that the issue might be that maxResults must be declared, and for some reason mine isn't working.  Even when I set the dimensions to 'day' and get an error-free report, the maxResults are never limited to the integer I assign it.  It will instead give 30 results since I have a 30 day range and am giving it a 'day' dimension.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just want to add a link to the specific documentation for using the video dimension: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#top-videos-reports  I feel like I'm following all the rules here.. (Note in AppsScript max-results is typed maxResults)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.  I was correct in assuming that they didn't like me using video as a dimension because maxResults was not working.

The correct way to format maxResults inside of AppsScript is:
    'max-results': '5'

So the completed, working, line of code is:

```
    var analyticsResponse = YouTubeAnalytics.reportsQuery('channel==' + channelId,
    oneMonthAgoFormatted,
    todayFormatted,
    'views', 

{
    dimensions: 'video',
    'max-results': '5',
    sort: '-views'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this `badRequest error` is happening because in the `dimensions` field, instead of placing a valid videoID, you instead placed the literal 'video' word. Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims#Resource_Dimensions):

> **video (core dimension)**
>
> The ID of a YouTube video. In the YouTube Data API, this is the value of a video resource's id property. This is
> a core dimension and is subject to the Deprecation Policy.

Comment: Are you sure that is not the correct usage?  It appears other answers on SO have successfully run similar code, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982845/unable-to-retrieve-video-metrics-using-youtube-analytics-api?rq=1

If that is not how the 'video' dimension should be used, what modifications should I make if I want a list of ad revenue sorted by video, instead of day?  I don't just want details of 1 video, I want an entire dimension to list the data requested for all videos.  Thanks!